# Form validation of empty strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I make the form first name input field not accept empty strings with space characters `"        "`

```
    <form asp-action="SaveRegistration" autocomplete="off">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Model:

```
public class ContactInfo
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

With `[Required]` attribute the user can still submit with a string with just space characters `"             "`

I know it's a simple question, but I am novice in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: you know, you can use [`[StringLength]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx) and.. what deters you from using `@Html.TextBoxFor()`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx try this?

Comment: @BagusTesa I am already using StringLength. How is `Html.TextBoxFor` better than `<input asp-for="FirstName"` ?

Comment: @Bola How does `MinLength` helps? I want to prevent user from entering string of just space characters, I don't want to restrict to a minimum length

Comment: `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]` - is this work? Sounds like you can write custom `RequiredAttribute` with `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` check.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto The value of AllowEmpyStrings is false by default

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the issue I think is in the validation in the generated JS client side code. It doesn't check for space characters strings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usage:

```
[NotNullOrWhiteSpaceValidator]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

How to make your own Attributes:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class NotNullOrWhiteSpaceValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public NotNullOrWhiteSpaceValidatorAttribute() : base("Invalid Field") { }
    public NotNullOrWhiteSpaceValidatorAttribute(string Message) : base(Message) { }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString())) return false;

        return true;        
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (IsValid(value)) return ValidationResult.Success;
        return new ValidationResult("Value cannot be empty or white space.");
    }
}
```

Here is implementation code for a bunch more validators: digits, email, etc: https://github.com/srkirkland/DataAnnotationsExtensions/tree/master/DataAnnotationsExtensions

Comment: Thanks! This is server side validation, correct? The form needs to be posted in order for the validation to kick in

Comment: Correct, many people add client-side JavaScript validation, you should always have server-side validation as shown encase JavaScript is disabled on the clients' browser, eg Chrome or even Nintendo Wii. Typically Validation methods will be called via `if (Model.IsValid)` in the Controller. It's also possible to call these validations earlier in the pipeline...

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a [regular expression](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

For example:

```
[RegularExpression(@".*\S+.*$", ErrorMessage = "Field Cannot be Blank Or Whitespace"))]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Nice. Albeit regular expressions are nasty.

Comment: as in, it works on C# side but sometimes wont on js side... look behind.

Comment: @BagusTesa "sometims wont" ? What does that even mean?

Comment: @SBFrancies I will mark your comment as answer, however I was looking for something better than RegExp. This can be avoided using ViewState.IsValid or having a custom client validation

Comment: Thanks - I agree, not a fan of regular expressions personally.

Comment: Is there a better way?

Comment: I am still looking for another way

Comment: I still don't know how to implement it without regular expressions

Comment: I don't know a better way that you can put on the model. If you want to validate on the client side then there are a lot of possible solutions but it's more easily bypassed.

Comment: @DonBox, if i remember correctly, javascript did not support lookbehind..

Comment: Yeah, a RegEx for IsNullOrEmpty is overkill, this is the correct way: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings.aspx

Comment: @DonBox Can't you just validate if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName )) server side before committing if you also want a server side solution?

Comment: @JeremyThompson the problem with that is the the user also wants to mark strings which are purely whitespace as invalid, not just empty strings.

Comment: Hmm - ok then, I'll reopen.

Comment: Check my answer, its a simpler and more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour is to **reject** empty strings. You can change this behaviour by setting `AllowEmptyStrings` to `true` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=netcore-3.1#examples)

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
```

Answer (score 1):

*Note:This is for .net MVC 4+*

There is a Implementation of **AllowEmptyStrings** within 
**[Required(ErrorMessage = " is required.")]**.

And this method returns true if an empty string is allowed; otherwise, false. The default value for this method is set to false. So no need to worry ! Test and verify the same.It should not allow single or multiple empty string.If not explicitly make it false and see if its work.

FYR`
{

```
public class RequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the 
           System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
        //     class.
        public RequiredAttribute();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value that indicates whether an empty string is 
       // allowed.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if an empty string is allowed; otherwise, false. The default 
        // value is false.
        public bool AllowEmptyStrings { get; set; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Checks that the value of the required data field is not empty.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   value:
        //     The data field value to validate.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if validation is successful; otherwise, false.
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   T:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationException:
        //     The data field value was null.
        public override bool IsValid(object value);
    }
```

}`

Answer (score -1):

**First**

You can try stringlength or minlength data annotation

**Second**

you can use 
[parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/)

Its an amazing library for client side form validation .

I will recommend you to use both client side and server side validation .

Comment: String Length or MinLength doesn't prevent whitespace.being valid